# Print GroupWise Sum details in another Group Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using jasper studio and I want to print Group wise sum in another group footer for better understanding take a look below.

Class Group Header: Class One

Student Group Header: Student One

```
 Subject | Total Marks | Obtained Marks
  ABC    |     100     |   50
  PQR    |     100     |   80
  AER    |     100     |   30
```

Student Group Footer:  Student One Total Obtained Marks : 160

Student Group Header: Student Two

```
 Subject | Total Marks | Obtained Marks
  ABC    |     100     |   20
  PQR    |     100     |   10
  AER    |     100     |   30
```

Student Group Footer:  Student Two Total Obtained Marks : 60

Here above i can print each student's obtained marks separately in student group footer, but i want to print same in Class group footer which means i want output like below

Class Group Header: Class One

Student Group Header: Student One

```
 Subject | Total Marks | Obtained Marks
  ABC    |     100     |   50
  PQR    |     100     |   80
  AER    |     100     |   30
```

Student Group Header: Student Two

```
 Subject | Total Marks | Obtained Marks
  ABC    |     100     |   20
  PQR    |     100     |   10
  AER    |     100     |   30
```

Class Group Footer:
Student One Total Obtained Marks : 160

Student Two Total Obtained Marks : 60

How can i achieve this result? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In Class group footer (or summary band) , drag and drop 'Crosstab' from pallete.

- Select Create a crosstab from existing database
- select column group = class
- select row group = Student
- select Measures = Marks /  calculation=sum

You can watch tutorials on how to use Crosstab in jasper studio